# celsius to fahrenheit

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is what i have i need for it to run and ask for celsius instead of fahrenheit but it is not doing it..

```
Dim celsius, fahrenheit As Double
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a celsius temperature:")
    celsius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32
    celsius = Math.Round(fahrenheit, 1)
    Console.WriteLine(celsius & " C =" & fahrenheit & " F")
```

I am not understand this at all i am suppose also ask users to input a celsius degree for this part.its telling me i nedd to change formula to calculate the fahrenheit temp for this part.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: And your question would be?  (Also, "its telling me" - what is telling you you need to change the formula?)  BTW, that second-to-last line looks odd; are you sure you're doing the right assignment?

Comment: Where is it telling you that you need to change the formula?

Comment: @yuriy He's clearly asking you to do his homework.

Comment: Ohh well in that case I take Paypal and he needs to email it to me.

Comment: Is this homework? Also I'm not a pro at VB but to me it looks like you are calculating `fahrenheit` then setting `celsius = fahrenheit` and outputting both variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim celsius, fahrenheit As Double
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a celsius temperature:")
    celsius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32
```

### fahrenheit = Math.Round(fahrenheit, 1)

```
    Console.WriteLine(celsius & " C =" & fahrenheit & " F")
```

Comment: ok i figure what i did to thanks guys what happen was i did mix up a few plus i had to put it under new project lol

Answer (score 1):

You are assignment is wrong here  - 
**`celsius = Math.Round(fahrenheit, 1)`**
should be assigned to fahrenheit ..Formulas are -

```
c=(5/9) * (fahrenheit - 32)
f=(9/5) * celsius  + 32
```

Corrected code -

```
  Dim celsius, fahrenheit As Double
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a celsius temperature:")
        celsius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
        fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32
        fahrenheit = Math.Round(fahrenheit, 1)//assign fahrenheit 
        Console.WriteLine(" C =" & celsius & " F=" & fahrenheit)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    Dim celsius, fahrenheit As Double
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a celsius temperature:")
    If Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), celsius) Then 'check input
        fahrenheit = celsius * 9.0R / 5.0R + 32.0R  'convert it
        Console.WriteLine("{0:F1}°C = {1:F1}°F", celsius, fahrenheit) 'show it
    End If
```

so you store the full precision number, but only display it with 1 decimal. Also using the `TryParse()` function is much safer as it does not throw an Exception if the input is not a number. Alternatively you can use `Conversion.Val()` which is much more robust than `Convert.ToDouble()`.